# Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just made a Chrome extension. I followed this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) to get a nice button in my toolbar. Now if I load a page, the javascript in my extension gets executed.

Unfortunately, if I click the extension's button in my toolbar, nothing happens.

Question: How do I make the js get executed when I click the extension's button in my toolbar?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**
I added background.html and it still doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  // Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var action_url = "javascript:mathjax.js";
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: action_url});
  });
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options.  Either, you can specify a `"popup": "popup.html"` in your `manifest.json`, then put the code in `popup.html`.  In this case, the code will get executed in the popup (though of course you can communicate with your background page or anything else).

Probably better would be to put a callback in `background.html` by attaching a listener to [chrome.browserAction.onClicked](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked).

Comment: Lovely, thank you, can you tell me how to attach a listener to onClicked?

Comment: I put this into background.html, but it still won't trigger: `<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Background Page</title>
    <script   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                           {code:"mathjax.js"});
    });></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>`

Comment: Odd... I'll play with it later today and see what's up.  What happens if you just try to surface an alert onClicked?

Comment: Thank you! I think the problem is with the mathjax queue. I posted a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397331/chrome-extension-revisited

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extension doesn't support inline javascript code in background.html.You must specify external javascript file.Also instead of specifying background.html you can directly specify external file in manifest file in background property.

I have answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168362/run-script-each-time-chrome-extension-icon-clicked/34553860#34553860).