# Chrome Extension Development: Action on extension disable

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm wondering if it's possible to have an action trigger when user disables/removes extension.

Possible actions:
Show html page genre "We hate to see you go. Please check our website"

Would something like this work for this purpose ?

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {   
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "myScript.js"}); 
});
```

with "myScript.js" holding the logic to execute on click.

taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168362/run-script-each-time-chrome-extension-icon-clicked)

edit : also found "No event will fire in case an extension is disabled or uninstalled"

might the onUninstalled event (from the API docs) not help me out here?

Comment: onUninstalled is not related to disabling an extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) browserAction.onClicked cannot be used for this task.

Since the only part of an extension that survives disabling/removing it is a content script, you can declare a content script that periodically tries to access your extension so a failure would indicate the extension is disabled.

Here's an example that displays a DOM element on the top of all open tabs:

manifest.json:

```js
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "run_at": "document_start",
  "all_frames": true,
  "js": ["ping.js"]
}]
```

ping.js:

```js
var pingTimer = setInterval(ping, 1000);

function ping() {
  var port = chrome.runtime.connect();
  if (port) {
    port.disconnect();
    return;
  }
  clearInterval(pingTimer);
  onDisabled();
}

function onDisabled() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    '<div style="all:unset; position:fixed; left:0; top:0; right:0; height:2rem;' +
    ' background:blue; color:white; font: 1rem/2rem sans-serif; z-index:2147483647;">' +
    'We hate to see you go. Please check our website: ' +
    '<a style="all:inherit; color:cyan; display:inline; position:static;"' +
    ' href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a></div>');
}
```

Notes:

- This will only work on pages that allow content script injection. In other words, all except the browser built-in pages like chrome://settings in chromium-based browsers or about:addons in Firefox-based ones, the extension/addon webstore site, other extensions' pages.
- Opening a new tab with your site will be problematic as content scripts can't access chrome.tabs API, and all other standard JavaScript methods to open a new tab will be blocked by the default popup-blocking policy, which can be manually altered by a user, though.
- Of several chrome API available in a content script only `chrome.runtime` survives disabling an extension, apparently.
- When you re-enable or reload your extension its content scripts aren't reinjected automatically into the open tabs! You'll need to do it manually in your background/event page script using chrome.tabs.query and chrome.tabs.executeScript. Search for examples on StackOverflow.

Comment: What an awesome elaborate (and quick) response to a noob question. Tnx so much for taking this seriously.

Dumbing this down for myself: 1) when a user removes the extension, the only thing I can do is inject a block of html into (all) tabs that are already open. I can't trigger a tab (with my site) to be opened.

2) If user closes down Chrome and starts up again will the content script still be there/will it survive? I guess not. So the "visit our site" message will only be visible during the initial browser session, correct? Next browser session will have nothing left of my extension.

Comment: let me know if you don't have anything to do this weekend :)
I have some work I'd be able to have commissioned.

Comment: Id also add to this answer that you can set an uninstall url to open when the user uninstalls the extension.

Comment: so above 1) IS possible ? I CAN in fact open a tab with my site to be opened when user removes extension ? Apparently this is supported since v41 of Chrome

Answer (score -3):

Hi You can also use this

```
chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL('http://myurl', function callback(id) {
        console.log("successfully uninstall");
    });
}
```

Comment: chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL runs right away and  callback is not going to execute when you uninstall your extension - Please refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077685/perform-activity-before-chrome-extension-is-getting-uninstalled