# How to run chrome extension that is made by Angular, inside iframe

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to implement a simple Chrome extension that renders its content not on a default popup , but on a sidebar. I've realized that to do that I must use an iframe due to its default behavior of chrome extension popup style.(which it has limitation of maximum width size of 800px and height 600px. And also unable to style its position).

[Angular Chrome Extension Scaffold Project](https://github.com/larscom/angular-chrome-extension)

Above the link is a github repository of a Angular Chrome extension scaffold project and I'm trying to build a chrome extension with Angular.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "extension test",
  "short_name": "extension test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "extension test",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "downloads",
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "extension test",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "assets/images/favicon-16.png",
      "32": "assets/images/favicon-32.png",
      "48": "assets/images/favicon-48.png",
      "128": "assets/images/favicon-128.png"
    }
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "index.html#/option",
    "open_in_tab": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["contentPage.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["backgroundPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "default_icon": {
    "16": "assets/images/favicon-16.png",
    "32": "assets/images/favicon-32.png",
    "48": "assets/images/favicon-48.png",
    "128": "assets/images/favicon-128.png"
  }
}
```

Above is my manifest.json file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Falcon Image Crawler</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's what index.html looks like.

and last here is how my App.component.ts looks like

```
export class PopupComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: `
      (function(){
      const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html');
      iframe.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;top:0;left:0;display:block;' +
        'width:300px;height:100%;z-index:1000;';
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    })(); `
    });
  }
}
```

When I click an icon of my chrome extension an Iframe element shows up left side of the browser but cannot load index.html with "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access a chrome:// URL" error and also popup shows up.

[image: image to describe its behavior]
(image to describe its behavior)

Is there a right way to run chrome extension not on its default popup but on a iframe that i can style it without any limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your `index.html` to the array of [Web accessible resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources), like so:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "extension test",
  "short_name": "extension test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "extension test",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "index.html"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "downloads",
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "extension test",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "assets/images/favicon-16.png",
      "32": "assets/images/favicon-32.png",
      "48": "assets/images/favicon-48.png",
      "128": "assets/images/favicon-128.png"
    }
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "index.html#/option",
    "open_in_tab": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["contentPage.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["backgroundPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "default_icon": {
    "16": "assets/images/favicon-16.png",
    "32": "assets/images/favicon-32.png",
    "48": "assets/images/favicon-48.png",
    "128": "assets/images/favicon-128.png"
  }
}
```

Also, you should not need to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` if you want to include your script in any page, but use the manifest syntax.

Comment: Thanks, adding index.html to web_accessible_resources field made index.html loadable. But how can I handle its default behavior of popup showing up when i click its icon on top of the browser?(you can see a small square on top of the image at the right top corner)

Comment: Just remove any of your popup code, and follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168362/run-script-each-time-chrome-extension-icon-clicked

In the handler, put your code that injects the script

Comment: 'Just remove any of your popup code' means removing "default_popup" inside "browser_action" field in manifest.json file right?

Comment: I believe the whole "browser_action" block can be removed

Comment: Thanks for your answers : )It helped me alot