# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onClicked')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension and for starter I want to print "hello world" (as of now), when user click on the icon of my extension.

I created a popup.js file and wrote the following code

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener('click', ()=>{
console.log("hello world")
 })
```

then i was faced with the error "**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onClicked')**" when i try to click my extension icon. Don't know what to do now.

Can *chrome.browserAction.onClick.addEventListener()* cannot run in popup.js script??

Here's my manifest.json file of the chrom extension.
P.S I have linked popup.js file with my popup.html file.

```
{
 "name": "club-tab",
  "description": "to club active tabs",
 "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
  "service_worker": "background.js",
  "type": "module"
},
  "action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
 "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab"],
 "host_permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

Comment: Look in [Run script each time Chrome extension icon clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168362/run-script-each-time-chrome-extension-icon-clicked)

Comment: There's no browserAction in ManifestV3, it's `action` and addListener has a different syntax (see the documentation first), but you don't need it anyway because popup.js runs automatically every time you open the popup. You also don't need the background script for this. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.